Where can I find Massachusetts Law on employee IP Assignment Agreements?
I'm trying to find any relevant Massachusetts law covering IP Assignment Agreements in employee contracts. I've been doing some googling but can only find relevant language for California.
For example I found this article: https://propertyintangible.com/2016/11/read-it-twice/
Which has the following language on California law:

(a) Any provision in an employment agreement which provides that an
employee shall assign, or offer to assign, any of his or her rights in
an invention to his or her employer shall not apply to an invention
that the employee developed entirely on his or her own time without
using the employer’s equipment, supplies, facilities, or trade secret
information except for those inventions that either:
(1) Relate at the time of conception or reduction to practice of the
invention to the employer’s business, or actual or demonstrably
anticipated research or development of the employer; or
(2) Result from any work performed by the employee for the employer.

I want to see what if any similar law exists in Massachusetts but I'm not sure where to look.

The relevant law in Massachusetts, if it exists, would be most likely to be located in the title of the Massachusetts statutes about labor and employment law (i.e. Title XXI). It might also be found in the case law of employment contracts.
This said, it is unlikely that there is parallel legislation or case law in Massachusetts to the legislation cited in California. In all probability, Massachusetts follows that default rule that  IP Assignment Agreements in employee contracts are enforceable as written, contrary to the California statute cited which expressly deviates from the common law rule.
To slightly oversimplify, in the regulation of employment, such as non-competition agreements and similar terms, particularly employment laws pertinent to the tech industry, Massachusetts has historically been strongly pro-employer, while California has historically been strongly pro-employee. There is a whole literature in economics on this phenomena (which has largely concluded that the approach of California is better at promoting economic growth in the industry than the Massachusetts approach).
